# git pull " fatal: Uh oh. Your system reports no Git commands at all."

Tags: git, pull, git-pull

since few days ago I'm working on a new server (moved from old to new with chroot user) 
from old server I've copied folder .git to a new server.

The problem is that when I type "git pull" then I have error:

> fatal: Uh oh. Your system reports no Git commands at all.

any other commands like git fetch or git merge works fine.

What reason is that I can't use git pull command?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have the binaries installed and in your `$PATH`.

Look for binaries named like `git-pull` in your binary directories, (e.g. `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, etc.).

If you notice that the files exist, ensure that the files are in a directory that is in your $PATH (simply check `echo $PATH` and see if the directory exists in that list (it is colon delimited).)

If the directory name isn't in the list of directories in the `$PATH`, you need to add the directory to the default `$PATH` in in your startup shell script, or at the beginning of every new terminal session, update the value with the directory those binaries are in by doing: `export PATH=$PATH:YOUR_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: result "echo $PATH" `/usr/lib/courier-imap/sbin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin` . git is located and exist in /usr/bin/

Comment: I noticed you said you "copied folder .git to a new server." Do the commands work appropriately if you didn't do that?

Answer (score -1):

git uses more than plain ssh, but requires an installation of git on the "server side" (the side where you pull from). your changeroot seems to lack those. add them and everything should work.

Comment: Please notice that commands git fetch and git merge works good. Only git pull give me this "fatal:".

Comment: @stefek143 sorry i missed that. can you try to do a debug run: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/git-client-debug/src/3929b1dc10110e8a40a10b8319b6fdd9ecfe5149/bin/git-debug-push?at=master

Answer (score -1):

For me, it was trying to use the /bin/git inside my cygwin installation folder. Also, when I added the actual GIT path into my PATH I did it at the end. The cygwin path was loaded before the actual PATH and hence the problem.

if you do "which git" it should tell you where your git lies.

Quick Fix: move the actual GIT PATH from the end (in the env var PATH list) to the beginning.